# When will the jwst python library have live data for the general public to work with in its data pipelines?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, space-telescope, python, raw-data

The [Space Science Telescope Institute](https://github.com/spacetelescope) has put out a python library called [JWST](https://github.com/spacetelescope/jwst) for science observations from [James Webb Space Telescope](https://www.jwst.nasa.gov/).

When will the general public be able to look at "live" detector data (live in the sense that the data was downloaded to NASA archives the day before, and the general public can download it to their local computers the next day)?

Comment: This might get better answers on [astronomy.stackexchange.com](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @fasterthanlight see [this meta post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2866/40257)

Comment: @fasterthanlight you keep leaving these incorrect close reasons even after it's been discussed so many times. The burden is on us to explain why it's off topic here, not where we think the question belongs.

Comment: Note that the downloaded information will contain operational information about the satellite (certainly it's attitude!) and we have plenty of questions about downloading the raw data from DSCOVR (earth observation) but not about raw data from Hubble (astronomy observation) so cases could be made that this is off-topic and on-topic. However I think that answers will definitely be better, and of more interest in Astronomy SE.

Comment: @uhoh I see that the subject of the meta post that was linked is me, seems like I still have that habit. Close vote retracted.

Comment: @fasterthanlight ya, OP decides where to ask, we decide if on-topic or not on-topic, and moderators decide if migration happens. We need to stay in our lanes and show new users *by example* that we do. Of course your comment is well-meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide some info on the question rather than where it should be posted, on the [JWST Town Hall webcast conducted on fri 1/28/22 (vod)](https://youtu.be/Pvot-JM3lwQ), one of the presenters stated that after the calibration/commissioning efforts are completed there will be a "big" data dump posted to the stsci (space telescope ....) archive.  That data will be publically available.  It was also stated that only a small fraction of it would be useful for scientific analysis.  The timing of this dump depends upon the progress of the calibration effort that has not yet begun.  After that ongoing data should be archived routinely.

Looks like some months before this dump.

tom kosvic

Comment: On the above referenced site there is a box labeled "View the JWST Town Hall".  This opens the podcast rerun. I asked a question on this webcast re: jwst data software and the answerer said that references would be posted below after end of broadcast. But I can't find any attached references.  If anyone sees any attachments, let me know